# HTML random value rapid test

Tags: javascript

I have this idea to prove a theory of mine.
So what I want to happen is when I run the program it will rapidly test a random chance. So, when I launched it it would rapidly test yes or no and there is a 1/1000000000 chance of "yes" and if it was yes, It would count one number up.

I browsed Stack Overflow and I found this:

```html
<html>
  <script>
    // Greetings
    var words = ['Hello', 'Hey', 'What\'s up!?'];

    function randomAlert() {

      // Index for picking the greeting you want to show
      var alertIndex;

      // Generates a number between 0 and 1
      var randomValue = Math.random();

      // 50% chance of 'Yes'
      if (randomValue < 0.5) {
        alertIndex = 0;
      }

      // 50% chance of 'No'
      else if(randomValue < 0.5) {
        alertIndex = 1;
      }



      alert(words[alertIndex])
    }
  </script>
  <button onClick="randomAlert()">Click me!</button>
</html>
```

But what happens is it makes the button and does what I want (does not work in stack overflow and i'm not sure why. It works when I run it as a file on my comp), but it does not count every time it comes out as "yes" and it has to be done manually. (That is why I have to make the chances so large)

I just read what I wrote and it sounds like I'm asking for a favor rather than asking to learn how to code it. Please, do not take this as a "job". I would like what functions to use to make a random value and rapidly test it. THNX

Comment: Both of your conditions check to see if the random value is less than .5. Also note that Math.random doesn't include 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do more than 1 draw, then you'll need a loop.
A `for` is the simplest, a `while` is also possible.

Also you'll need to have counters for each 'low or high' outcome.

I have made those changes, with a slightly different chance setting to keep it from running forever, with this result:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function randomCount() {
    var countLow = 0;
    var countHigh = 0;
    var cutOff = 1 / 1000;
    var totalTries = 10000;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalTries; i++) {
      var randomValue = Math.random();
      if (randomValue < cutOff)
        countLow++;
      else
        countHigh++;
    }
    console.log("Result: countLow = " + countLow + ", countHigh = " + countHigh + ".");
  }
</script>
<button onClick="randomCount()">Click me!</button>
```